# Set Bitbucket triggers based on Jira issue labels

Tags: bitbucket, jira

What I am trying to achieve:

If there's a certain Label set in Jira's issue I want to automatically decline Pull Request (with comment, if possible) if this label is in issue of type bug.

Is it possible to do such thing?

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not possible by default and I'm not aware of any add-on on the marketplace that is able to do it.

However, you can create some scripts to achieve this. You can create a custom listener (via [ScriptRunner](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/apps/6820/scriptrunner-for-jira?hosting=server&tab=support) add-on) to watch changes on Labels and then change/decline the linked PR over REST API.

Alternatively, you can script a custom merge check on Bitbucket side (if Bitbucket is used) checking the linked Jira issue's labels and blocking the PR from merging if condition is met. [ScriptRunner for Bitbucket](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/apps/1213250/scriptrunner-for-bitbucket?hosting=server&tab=overview) would be used instead.

**Note:** It depends what DCVS you use and if you use on-premise Jira (Server/DC) or Cloud one.